# unable to use IPAddress or similar type in windows 8 metro style apps

Tags: sockets, windows-8

I am finding difficulty in using `System.Net.IPAddress` or any similar types in Windows 8 Metro Apps. I am creating an application that will  run in an intranet environment and the users will connect to remote servers using IPAddress.

But somehow I am not able to use it. Also, in `Windows.Networking.EndpointPair` class, I cant find any option to pass IPAddress specifically

Kindly help with this.
Thanx of help in advance

Comment: "But somehow I am not able to use it."  <-- why not?  What happens when you try?  Can you show what code you tried, and/or what error messages you received from the compiler or the runtime?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: System.Net is available but class IPAddres is not available

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [HostName class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.hostname.aspx) to represent an IP Address.  When you create the [EndpointPair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.endpointpair.aspx), you have a remote and a local host.  Check out the [StreamSocket sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/StreamSocket-Sample-8c573931).  System.Net.IPAddress is not part of the .NET Core Profile and is thus not available from Metro style apps.