# C# - WinRT - Convert IPv6 address stored as a byte array to string

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, ipv6

I have an IPv6 address provided as a `byte[16]` array and I would like to convert it to `string` (for the purpose of logging).

I would normally achieve this in C# using the `System.Net.IPAddress` constructor, but it seems that `System.Net.IPAddress` is not available in C# for WinRT/Windows Store. Does anyone have an equivalent way to do this conversion/formatting?

Comment: Oh and I know there is a very long way to do this (by looking up the .NET reflector code for IPAddress.ToString()) and seeing how MS handles this internally) but i'm hoping to find something already built-in to C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this manually by just creating the full IPv6 string two bytes at a time with colon seperator. Then, I passed that string to Windows.Networking.HostName and accessed it's DisplayName property, which gave me back the compressed version (i.e. 0000 replaced with 0 and with a single :: replacement if applicable).

At least HostName saved me *some* of the work :) It's still a shame that there isn't a full IPAddress replacement though :(

Answer (score 1):

Converting a byte array to a valid IPv6 address is easy enough.

```
// Precondition: bytes.Length == 16
string ConvertToIPv6Address(byte[] bytes)
{
    var str = new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i+=2)
    {
        var segment = (ushort)bytes[i] << 8 | bytes[i + 1];         
        str.AppendFormat("{0:X}", segment);
        if (i + 2 != bytes.Length)
        {
            str.Append(':');
        }           
    }

    return str.ToString();
}
```

Collapsing empty segments is a little more involved, but generally not needed for anything other than display purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [`Windows.Networking.HostName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.hostname.aspx) is the replacement for `IPAddress`.

*Edit*: But I'm not sure that you can create one from a `byte[]`.

See also:

- [unable to use IPAddress or similar type in windows 8 metro style apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068940/unable-to-use-ipaddress-or-similar-type-in-windows-8-metro-style-apps)

Comment: Thanks, I had also looked at Windows.Networking.Hostname - but i'm still not clear how to take this byte array and end up with a string representation of the IPv6 address :( This was a lot easier with System.Net.IPAddress